# Error while posting data from ASP.Net 4.5 to ASP.Net 2.0 web application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

We caught up in the following scenario:

- We have a web application which runs on .Net 2.0 framework.
- Customer has a web application which runs on .Net 4.5 framework.

When they are posting data from one of their page to our pages, we are getting system errors.  To validate the issue I have deployed two web applications on same server and tried to post a form from webapp 1 (on 4.5) to webapp 2 (on 2.0).  I am getting below error.

```
[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: 127.0.0.1
Port: 63153
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
ViewState: /wEPDwUKLTM1MTA1NjA1MmRk6CPd6yG4r8HEbqBZi3i4jiLLnZotIlX7+6zAZaceaGY=
Referer: http://localhost/test4/default.aspx
Path: /test2/default.aspx]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.]
System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +148
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +11065601
System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +59
System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +11065704
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +11150648
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +46
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11146167
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11145706
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +91
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +240
ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in     c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET     Files\test2\b4717a74\d7ba8639\App_Web_ha1suqrp.0.cs:0
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +599
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171
```

I tried the following:

- EnableViewState = false in Page tag.  But still .Net is adding a
  _VIEWSTATE hidden variable.
- Added a Javascript function to set _VIEWSTATE hidden variable to
  empty.  This resolved the issue.

Though second work solutions resolved the problem, I am looking for better ways to solve this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnableViewState = false` only turns off the ViewState, but not the control state of the ASP.NET server controls, that's why you still have the hidden VIEWSTATE control.

The ViewState is hash coded on the server, therefore you should use the same key's to generate the hash. You set the `<machinekey>` in your machine.config file to the same value on both applications/servers. The default value is `AutoGenerate`, which means that every server has it's own machinekey. You find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx)

As an alternative you turn the hashing off by setting `EnableViewstateMac` to false (basically what your error message says). By doing this users could manipulate your ViewState.

Comment: I have hosted both the applications on same server.  Also after reading your reply, followed the post to Apply constant key set for all the applications on the same server.  Also I have set the EnableViewstateMac to false on Web App 1, but I am still getting the above error while posting data from 4.5 application to 2.0 application.  Additional case I tested is, posting data from a .Net 2.0 application to .Net 2.0 application.  They are working properly.

Comment: the machine.config files of the 2 .NET Versions are in different directories. And I cannot believe that you get the error, when you turn off EnableViewStateMac. I would try to turn it off on both pages.

Comment: Setting EnableViewStateMac to false on both site pages resolved the issue.  This has to be done on top of configuring same Machine Keys for all the web sites.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you need one or the other to solve the problem. Either turn off EnableViewStateMac or set the same MachineKeys. The later is the better.